# Is there a way to sum up the values of textboxes that are not visible by default

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have three textboxes which only show when a button is checked then subsequently the values in the text boxes are summed up. My existing solution is returning empty using   ![Bill] = Nz((Me.txtPharmAmt1 + Me.txtPharmAmt2+ Me.txtPharmAmt3), 0).

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with SQL, so I'm removing the tag.

Comment: I was hoping I could query the database based on the values supplied in the textboxes. Thanks

Comment: What is returning empty - the query? If any of those fields is null the arithmetic will return Null and therefore the overall result would be 0. Apply Nz() function individually to each field. How do you want to use this expression to query the data? Visibility has nothing to do with the calc result.

Comment: Thank you June 7. I have found a way around it. I created a hidden textbox in the footer and equate it to the summation of the textboxes values based on the condition of when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I created a hidden textbox (txtTotal) in the footer and equate it to the summation of the textboxes values based on the condition of when the button is clicked.
i.e

```
if chkbtn1 is True Then
txtTotal=txtBox1 + txtBox2
elseif chkbtn2 is True Then
txtTotal=txtBox1 + txtBox2 +txtBox3
```